# Call a swift instance function from ObjC when the function's class does NOT inherit from NSObject

Tags: objective-c, swift

Is there a way to do that? What does the call look like supposing the function is "myFunc" in:

```
@objc class ClassTwo {
    func myFunc() -> () {
        println("class ClassTwo instance function myFunc")
    }
}
```

IOW calling myFunc from swift looks like the following, so how do I write the same call in ObjC?

```
ClassTwo().myFunc()
```

Comment: I wish people who down vote a question would leave a brief comment explaining their vote. This seems to me like a perfectly valid question, clearly stated, brief, and about a valid programming topic. And I had first searched for an answer without finding it. And it got a good informative answer. So I'm left to wonder what's the problem? I suppose the down voter knew the answer him/herself so considered it too trivial but I don't think that's a reason to down vote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `ClassTwo` isn't a subclass of `NSObject`, it doesn't provide the standard `alloc` method for allocating an instance. If you're going to create your instances of `ClassTwo` in Swift and just make existing instances available to Objective-C (by passing them to Objective-C methods or storing them in properties), that's not a problem. But if you want to create instances of `ClassTwo` in Objective-C, you need to provide a way to do that. Example:

```swift
@objc class ClassTwo {
    class func make() -> ClassTwo {
        return ClassTwo()
    }

    func myFunc() -> () {
        println("class ClassTwo instance function myFunc")
    }
}
```

To use `ClassTwo` from an Objective-C `.m` file, you need to import *project*`-Swift.h` (where *project* is the name of your project). Then you can call class methods of `ClassTwo` and instance methods of `ClassTwo` instances, like this:

```objc
#import "AppDelegate.h"
#import "project-Swift.h"

@implementation AppDelegate

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    ClassTwo *two = [ClassTwo make];
    [two myFunc];

    return YES;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

rob mayoff's answer is right. `ClassTwo`, when bridged to Objective-C, is not declared to have `+alloc`. However, as part of Objective-C compatibility, all Swift classes in practice have a basic subset of NSObject methods, including `+alloc`; it's just not publicly declared as such, so the compiler doesn't know.

If you don't want to add another method to your class, another solution is to declare (but not implement) in Objective-C a dummy category that declares `+alloc`, so that the compiler will think the class has `+alloc`, and will allow `[[ClassTwo alloc] init]` to compile.

```
@interface ClassTwo (Alloc)
+ (instancetype)alloc;
@end
```

Comment: Amazing! and really cool. Thanks for that. I haven't tried it yet but I'm assuming that if it will compile it will also link and run.

Comment: @RobertL: In `[[ClassTwo alloc] init]`, the only thing that is linked is `ClassTwo`, so yes it should link.